# Lookup a Value and Display Column Header

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, lookup, worksheet-function

```
aaa  bbb  ccc  D
1    5    9    # (aaa, bbb or ccc)
2    6    10
3    7    11
4    8    12
```

I am trying to find a formula (to go in D2) so that the number matches its column header (`aaa`, `bbb` or `ccc`). For example if I put `5` in cell D1, D2 displays `bbb`, `11` will display `ccc` and so on.

Comment: cell to contain aaa or bbb or ccc depends on the number in the cell

Comment: The formula go into cell D2, number goes into cell D1.
and depends on the number, the cell D1 should display "aaa" for 1~4, "bbb" for 1~8 and so on.
Something like If cell D1=1~4, display text "aaa" if cell D1=5~8, "bbb" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the numbers run 1>12 in your example merely for illustration and `1` is in A2, hence suggest:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(D1,A:A,0)),IF(ISERROR(MATCH(D1,B:B,0)),C1,B1),A1)
```

Comment: This is great thank you so much pnuts. But problem is that i have more than just 3 columns on my example. and it shows error saying too many argument... I have about 8 columns. Any suggestions?